# ion-auth codeigniter doesnt open

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

Hey guys so I have an application that a friend sent me and I'm trying to get it working on my localhost WAMP server. It implements a development environment known as CodeIgniter and it uses a plugin called "Ion auth". I can't seem to get the application working...

When I go to 'localhost' in my address bar the index.php redirects me to `/auth/login` and there I am prompted with a login screen, the ion-auth screen. When I type in the default username & password and click login, it reloads the page and above the login form it just says "In-Correct Login". I don't know what the problem is.

I'm using the default configuration for ion-auth. I followed the docs on benedmunds website and a youtube tutorial to set up the configuration files but I'm stuck on this and I don't understand why it doesn't log in.

Comment: Well usually when it says `"In-Correct Login"`, it means the credentials are wrong. (*Username/Password are incorrect or do not match.*). Probably best to ask your friend what said username & password are since he `"gave"` you the code right?

Comment: Yes. He gave me the code, but the password is supposed to be `password` and the email is `foo@bar.com` and it doesn't log me in... he had the same problem but he asked me to try, i don't know either.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default file of Ion-Auth and have not changed any code in

`controller/auth.php` ,

then try the link

`http://localhost/project_name/auth/create_user`

to create new user. And try logging in with that user. Also check the config file of Ion-Auth about the account activation. If

`$config['email_activation'], $config['manual_activation']`

are set true, then set it to false. Also for current login you are trying make sure it is activated in the database.

To make this user active, go to user table in the database and set `'active'` column to 1. Make sure you have properly set up the ion_auth.php in config folder.